# How to make my 'Rock, Paper, Scissors Game' stop at 6 points?

Tags: javascript

This is my Javascript Code so far. I can get it to run properly but the points, for the computer and player, will keep going up until I press *Restart Game.* I attempted to add variables to lose, win, and draw but it won't change the fact it goes above 6 points. I'm currently an Odin Project Student and they want me to attempt to add something that will make it stop at a certain amount of points and I don't know if I should add an If or and Else statement.

```
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_div = document.querySelector(".result > p");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("r");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("p");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("s");


function getComputerChoice() {

  const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return choices[randomNumber];
}


function convertToWord(letter) {
if (letter === "r") return "Rock";
if (letter === "p") return "Paper";
if (letter === "s") return "Scissors";

}


function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  result_div.innerHTML = convertToWord(userChoice) + " Beats " + convertToWord(computerChoice) + ". You Won!";

 

 
}


function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  computerScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  result_div.innerHTML = convertToWord(userChoice) + " Loses To " + convertToWord(computerChoice) + ". You Lost!";
}


function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  result_div.innerHTML = convertToWord(userChoice) + " Is Equal To "+ convertToWord(computerChoice) + ". It's A Draw!";
  
}


function game(userChoice){
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch(userChoice + computerChoice){
    case "rs":
    case "pr":
    case "sp":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;

      case "rp":
      case "ps":
      case "sr":
        lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
        break;

      case "rr":
      case "pp":
      case "ss":
        draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? And how is this problem related to CSS?

Comment: I've tried to add functions in win, lose, and draw and it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Put the contents of your `game` function in a loop, keep track of the player's points outside of the loop, then break out of the loop when the points reach 6.